# Rendering user post JSON data in react native

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, react-native

Hello i'm currently working with React native using my rails api to retrieve user micropost data. The data renders in my log but comes up blank in react native. Honestly not sure what i'm doing wrong. can anyone help? Maybe the JSON is the problem?

Here is the JSON data:

```
[{"id":4,"content":"fool","user_id":1,"created_at":"2018-06-21T00:50:08.343Z","updated_at":"2018-06-21T00:50:08.343Z","picture":{"url":null}},{"id":3,"content":"pool\r\n","user_id":1,"created_at":"2018-06-21T00:50:04.644Z","updated_at":"2018-06-21T00:50:04.644Z","picture":{"url":null}},{"id":2,"content":"cool","user_id":1,"created_at":"2018-06-16T04:26:11.020Z","updated_at":"2018-06-16T04:26:11.020Z","picture":{"url":null}}]
```

And Here is my React Native code:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { FlatList, StyleSheet, Text, View, AsyncStorage } from "react- 
native";

const ACCESS_TOKEN = 'access_token';

export default class App extends Component {
state = {
data: []
};

componentWillMount() {
this.fetchData();
}

fetchData = async () => {
let accessToken = await AsyncStorage.getItem(ACCESS_TOKEN);
const response = await fetch("https://example.com/api/users/"+accessToken);
const json = await response.json();
this.setState({ data: json.data });
};

render() {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
     <FlatList
      data={this.state.data}
      keyExtractor={item => item.toString()}
      renderItem={({ item }) =>
        <Text>
          //also tried {`${item.content}`}, didn't work
         {`${item.microposts.content}`}
       </Text>}
      />
    </View>
    );
  }
}

 const styles = StyleSheet.create({
 container: {
 marginTop: 15,
 flex: 1,
 justifyContent: "center",
 alignItems: "center",
 backgroundColor: "#F5FCFF"
 }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Remove the extra `}`
2. Please optimize code by declaring renderItem as such

   ```
   renderItem={({ item }) => <Text>{item.microposts && item.microposts.content}</Text>}
   ```